# Wordpress get_posts not working as expected

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to retrieve posts in Wordpress using the `get_posts` function, trying to filter by a custom field named `cegep_region` but the method is returning posts with any value in this field. My query below:

```
$cegep = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'cegep',
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            'key' => 'cegep_region',
            'value' => '386',
            'compare' => '='
        )
    ));
```

When I look into the database, `386` is not what there is in the `meta_value`.

```
select * from wp_postmeta where post_id=577 and meta_key='cegep_region'
```

What can I possibly be doing wrong?

Comment: What's in the `meta_value` then? You could also skip the `meta_query` and just use `'meta_key' => 'cegep_region'` and `'meta_value_num' => 386`

Comment: @disinfor any number. It's not filtering. I tried using only meta_key and meta_value and it worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try without using compare and add one more array inside in meta_query

```
$args = array(
    post_type' => 'cegep',
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'cegep_region',
            'value' => 386,
        )
    )
);
$postslist = get_posts( $args );
```

its work fine with me

Comment: Thanks for your answer I did. It doesn't work. But I found that removing the meta_query and addinf meta_key and meta_value works